# Relative de Rham Cohomology is Homotopy Invariant

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose $ f:N\rightarrow M$ is a smooth map between two manifolds. Relative de Rham cohomology is defined through the complex $ \Omega^{q}(f)=\Omega^{q}(M)\oplus\Omega^{q-1}(N)$ with $d(\omega,\theta)=(d\omega,f^{*}\omega-d\theta)$.

I'm trying to show that this relative cohomology is homotopy-invariant as in if $ f $ and $ g $ are homotopic maps from $ N $ to $ M $, the induced relative cohomologies are isomorphic algebras.

I've been trying to define a chain map between the following exact sequence $$0\rightarrow\Omega^{q-1}(N)\rightarrow\Omega^{q}(f)\rightarrow\Omega^{q}(M)\rightarrow 0$$ and the corresponding one for $g$, and after that use naturality and five lemma. The maps in the short exact sequences are inclusion and projection. I haven't been able to get this to work so far. Could you please help?

Edit: If you have another method to prove the same result, I'm also interested in that. The book I'm reading (Bott - Tu) hasn't introduced singular cohomology at this point, so I cannot use it.

Comment: It will be true that $f^*\omega=g^*\omega$ as cohomology classes, since homotopic maps induce the same maps on de Rham cohomology to begin with. Are you trying to prove this as an independent result?

Comment: You can look at the homotopy $F:N \times [0,1] \rightarrow M$ and consider the mapping cone complex corresponding to this map $\Omega(F)$ and show that it has the same homology as the mapping cone complex for $f$ and $g$. You won't get a map between $\Omega(f)$ and $\Omega(g)$. To avoid having to deal with manifolds with boundary you can do this for singular homology instead.

Comment: @Connor I know that $ f $ and $ g $ induce the same map on cohomology. How can I use this to prove the isomorphism?

Comment: @PeterM Sorry, I may have missed that you wanted an actual isomorphism of algebras. If $f^*=g^*$, then you'll get the same boundary map and hence the same chain complex and cohomologies. As in the approach that apurv suggested, this also won't give you an actual map between the two.

Comment: @Connor I'm sorry if I'm not making myself clear. I'm just interested in proving the existence of an algebra isomorphism using what the book has introduced so far. Constructing an explicit isomorphism is a plus but not necessary. $ f $ and $ g $ are the same on cohomology but not chains. Which boundary map do you mean? Would you mind spelling out the details?

Comment: Look at Proposition 6.49 in Bott and Tu. If $f^*$ and $g^*$ are the same on cohomology, then is there anything you can say about their respective long exact sequences in 6.49?

Comment: @Connor Thank you. So both fit in a long exact sequence with the same maps. The theorems I'm familiar with to establish an isomorphism (like five lemma), require an already existing map between $ \Omega(f) $ and $ \Omega(g) $ to make a diagram commutative. I tried to use the identity but it doesn't take kernel elements to kernel elements. I don't know what to do next...

Answer (score 2):

- Suppose given a diagram of cochain complexes 
  $$\begin{array} AA & =& A \\ \downarrow{f} & & \downarrow{g} \\ B &
     \stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} & C.   \end{array} $$
  If $h$ is a homotopy equivalence, with homotopy inverse $h'$  also commuting with $f$ and $g$, then the induced map on [mapping cones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_(homological_algebra))
  $$\mathrm{cone}(f) \xrightarrow{h_*} \mathrm{cone}(g)$$
  is a homotopy equivalence with homotopy inverse $h'_*$. (Use a homotopy $1_B \simeq hh'$ to construct a homotopy $1_{\mathrm{cone}(f)} \simeq h_*h'_*$.)
- Now consider homotopic maps $f, g : N \to M$ of smooth manifolds, with a homotopy $$K: f \to g : N \times I \to M.$$ Let $i_0$ and $i_1$ be the inclusions $N \to N \times I$ of the fibres over $0$ and $1$ respectively, so that $i_0^*K = f$ and $i_1^*K = g$. By the homotopy invariance of usual de Rham cohomology, the maps $i_0^*$ and $i_1^*$ in the diagram below
  $$\begin{array} A \Omega_M & =& \Omega_M & = & \Omega_M\\ \downarrow{f^*} & & \downarrow{K^*} & & \downarrow{g^*} \\ \Omega_N & 
     \stackrel{i_0^*}{\longleftarrow} & \Omega_{N \times I} &  \stackrel{i_1^*}{\longrightarrow} & \Omega_N   \end{array} $$ 
  are homotopy equivalences of cochain complexes. Therefore, using a homotopy inverse of $i_0^*$, we obtain a diagram

  $$\begin{array} A\Omega_M & =& \Omega_M \\ \downarrow{f^*} & & \downarrow{g^*} \\ \Omega_N &
     \stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} & \Omega_N.   \end{array} $$
  in which $i$ is a homotopy equivalence. By the previous bullet, this implies that we have a homotopy equivalence $\mathrm{cone}(f^*) \simeq \mathrm{cone}(g^*)$, and taking cohomology we have the result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to answer this, but I'm working through Bott and Tu myself now and had the exact same issue, so I figure why not post.

As you say, we want to use the five lemma on this diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\rightarrow H^{q-1}(M) @>>f^*> H^{q-1}(N) @>>> H^{q}(f) @>>> H^{q}(M) @>>f^*> H^{q}(N) \rightarrow\\
@| @| @VV?V @| @| \\
\rightarrow H^{q-1}(M) @>>g^*> H^{q-1}(N) @>>> H^{q}(g) @>>> H^{q}(M) @>>g^*> H^{q}(N) \rightarrow\\
\end{CD}$$
We know that $f^* = g^*$, but we need a well defined map $H^{q}(f) \to H^{q}(g)$. As you point out in the comments, the chain level identity map does not send closed forms to closed forms. But we can create such a map using a fixed homotopy $F: N \times I \to M$. Let $i_0, i_1: N \to N \times I$ be the inclusions to $N \times \{0\}$ and $N \times \{1\}$ respectively, so that $F \circ i_0 = f$ and $F \circ i_1 = g$. Also let $p_0: N \times I \to N$ be the projection onto $N \times \{0\}$.

Now suppose $(\omega, \theta) \subset \Omega^q(M) \oplus \Omega^{q-1}(N) = \Omega^q(f)$ is closed, so $i_0^* F^* \omega = f^* \omega = d\theta$. Since $i_0$ is a homotopy equivalence, $F^*\omega$ is exact as well; write $F^* \omega = d\Theta$ for some $\Theta \in \Omega^{q-1}(N \times I)$. Next, define $\Theta' = \Theta - p_0^*(i_0^*\Theta - \theta).$ Note that
$$d\Theta' = d\Theta - p_0^*(i_0^* d\Theta - d\theta) = d\Theta - p_0^*(i_0^*F^*\omega - f^*\omega) = d\Theta = F^*\omega \tag{1}$$
and
$$i_0^*\Theta' = i_0^*\Theta - i_0^*p_0^*i_0^*\Theta + i_0^*p_0^*\theta = \theta, \tag{2}$$
since $p_0 \circ i_0$ is the identity. Modulo exact forms, $\Theta'$ is the unique $(q-1)$-form on $N \times I$ satisfying (1) and (2). That's because (1) determines $\Theta'$ up to closed forms, and (2) fixes the cohomology class of $i_0^*\Theta' - \theta$. Finally we can define our map $H^q(f) \to H^q(g)$ by $[(\omega, \theta)] \mapsto [(\omega, i_1^*\Theta')]$.

This is well defined. Trivially the square to the right of the arrow in the diagram above commutes. For the box on the left, note that if $\omega = 0$ and $\theta$ is closed, then we may take $\Theta' = p_0^*\theta$, and then our map becomes $[(0,\theta)] \mapsto [(0,\theta)]$. The five lemma gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do anything weird here (like the five lemma)

It's a simple consequence of prop6.49's long exact sequence:

$$...\rightarrow H^q(f)\rightarrow H^q(M)\rightarrow H^q(S)\rightarrow H^{q+1}(f)\rightarrow ...$$

Remember long exact sequence can be split into short exact sequences which must split because we are dealing with vector spaces here. We have $H^q(S)=coker f^\ast\oplus ker f^\ast$, here $f^\ast$ is the pullback map $H^\ast(M)\rightarrow H^\ast(S)$. Same with $g^\ast$.